# InputStream cannot work only in Android 7.0(API 24)

Tags: android, inputstream, android-7.0-nougat

This problem only occurs in android 7.0(api 24).
Android 4.0,5.0,6.0 versions work perfectly.

```
Resources res = getResources();
 InputStream lisansStream = res.openRawResource(R.raw.xxx);
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: attempt to get length of null array

Comment: There is no `R.test` set of resources. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. That would include the full Java stack trace and the *actual* code that is generating it.

Comment: okey.I did edit

Comment: The edit seems not to be enough. At least to me.